# I have my tsconfig set as specified in order to use await at top level of module, but still getting error. How do I fix this error?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, ts-node, top-level-await

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Docs: [https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) */
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "outDir": "bin",
    "rootDir": "/",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": ["node", "mocha"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false // TypeScript 4.4+ only!
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "nodenext"
    }
  },
  "include": ["app/**/*.ts", "config/**/*.js", "test/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "<node_internals>/**", "./built/**/*"]
}
```

This is the **error:**

```
Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.ts(1378)
```